# MVC Form Post with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model

So I have an action method like this:

```
public ViewResult CareerSearch()
{
    CareerSearchModel model = GetCareerSearchModel();

    return View("Search", model);
}
```

In the view, I manually create a list of checkboxes from one of the model properties. The output of that ends up looking something like this:

```
<input id="location51438342" type="checkbox" checked="True" value="2" name="locations">
<label for="location51438342">Austin</label>
<input id="location14609737" type="checkbox" checked="True" value="9" name="locations">
<label for="location14609737">Dallas</label>
<input id="location25198218" type="checkbox" checked="True" value="11" name="locations">
<label for="location25198218">Houston</label>
```

So, on the action method that handles the form POST, I want to get a reference to the model AND the checkbox integer array. However, when I step through the following action method, "model" is null:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult CareerSearch(CareerSearchModel model, int[] locations)
{
    //omitted for brevity
}
```

What am I missing here? How do I get the reference to my model AND the array of checkbox values?

Comment: Does the model have a property called "locations" that you are trying to bind? Or are you referring to other properties that you aren't showing in the example?

Answer (score 0):

you'd have to be posting back all the fields of the model itself too aka have them in hiddenfor labels inside of the form. you can use firebug to see what is posted back. if it's not being posted back you'd have to recreate it in your action after the post.

Answer (score 0):

The model is not saved anywhere on the server and is not automatically posted back in the POST data (use Fiddler to confirm). You must instantiate the model the same way you do in the GET action and use the other parameters to modify it accordingly.

See [NerdDinner](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part5.htm) on how to map POST form data into your model.